# Blender export to three.js JSON only processing one geometry object

Tags: json, three.js, blender, exporter

I'm pretty new to three.js so bear with me!

I'm a seasoned user of Blender and have looking for the best way to export to a three.js importer.

So far, the most successful has been the obj importer, although I would love to include animations.  With this in mind, I have tried the Collada dae importer (a bit hit and miss) and am now on the JSON route.

I have successfully (I hope) added the JSON export addon into Blender (2.74) which does now export JSON files.  These work OK when imported into three.js, but for some reason, it is only exporting one object when I have several in the scene.  I have also checked the JSON file and there is only one set of vertices.

I have read on older posts that it has something to do with parenting, but I can't export the scene as it breaks when imported for some reason.

The reason I want multiple objects is because I want to animate various objects within a scene using keyframes.  Sounds easy?  Not so much.

Are there any specific limitations of bone-based (on armatures) animations.  I have a feeling it may have something to do with the object parenting to the bones?

My error could be in the JSON importer in the three.js file...

The documentation on this is a bit limited so any advice would be welcome.

Comment: I'm commenting to confirm that, although I am new to Stackoverflow, I am still watching this post and will gladly answer any questions anyone has.

Comment: You may have better luck if you show your code and ask a specific question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK - code is hosted on Dropbox at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o8665a7j6eawrow/AABxySqKgM9WhPUoW69k2FGRa?dl=0

Comment: There are three files - the original test .blend file (created in ver 2.74) with animation and two separate objects.  Then there is the json exported file and the html to load it up.  My specific question is... why is the io_three export script only exporting one object?  My next question is why isn't my animation working?  What I mean by not working is that the html shows only one box and it's not animated as it was set up in Blender.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, I really can't get my head around this.  I've now amended the webgl_loader_json_blender example to cut out the dae file and the monster.js example works.  If I then take the monster.blend file and export   to json using the blender exporter, the loader script fails.  I can only hazzard a guess that the exporter is not exporting the same thing as the exampke file given.  Either that or some of the json export options are ticked when they shouldn't be.  For some reason, objects exported without scene seem to work but when the scene is included, it fails.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I would suggest that you try making a new 3-sentence post and just ask a simple question. I'd help you here if I could.

Comment: Will do... but I think I know what the source of the problem is.  The example json loader within the github/three.js heirarchy loads a previous version .js file.  The current JSON exporter for Blender 2.74 exports as a JSON file and there are no working examples to import an animated JSON file.  With this in mind, I don't even know where to start with a JSON loader.  Perhaps I'll make a new post asking for a current JSON loader for three.js.

Comment: Question re-started at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476723/blender-2-7x-exporter-to-json-for-three-js-jsonloader