# Blender 2.7X Exporter to .json For three.js JSONLoader

Tags: json, three.js, export, blender

I am trying to export from Blender into Three.js using the JSON route (for animations)

Three.js version r71

Blender version 2.74

The current Blender exporter successfully exports a **.json** file *NOT* a .js file.

All examples within the r71 folders import .js files only.

Does anyone have any working examples on how to import a .json file that has been exported from Blender 2.7x?

If not, I'll have to go back to Blender 2.69 and use the commonly documented .js import.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but .json files are just .js but with a different extension.
If you open a .json file you can see it is purely a JSON object declared inside a variable, like you would do in plain javascript.

You can still load the JSON files through the JSONLoader object, just declare a new object inside a variable:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
```

And then with the method `.load` you can load your exported file as first argument and a callback function to apply the exported mesh and the exported material into the scene.

```
jsonLoader.load('path_to/exported_model.json', function (geometry, materials) {

  yourModel = new THREE.Mesh(
    geometry,
    new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )
  );

  scene.add(yourModel);

});
```

[Working example with multiple JSON exports](http://luigimannoni.github.io/experiments/clock-webgl/) and [the running javascript](http://luigimannoni.github.io/experiments/clock-webgl/javascripts/main.js) for it.

Comment: Thank you for this.  The two sample files I was working with looked different, but if the two are effectively the same, perhaps its the geometry format type.  I've seen a few posts about types 3 and 4 on mrdoobs blogs but it doesn't make it clear which is churned out by Blender.  Either way, the geometry format exported by Blender is not accepted by the current commit version of the JSONLoader.  To be honest, both Babylon.js and Blend4Web have much better documentation in this area so I might head in that direction.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware three.js lacks a bit of documentation on certain areas (and some features they are meant to be still WIP, that's why some stuff isn't clear enough) but I am pretty sure mrdoob and the guys are doing their best writing documentation on the go. Regarding the jsonloader I have seen on the last commit (r71) the changelog states a change for the Blender exporter, although I can't see any changes related to the jsonloader. I can suggest you to try using the r69/r70 exporter and loader and have it a go. If you have time please flag this issue on their github repo.

Comment: Have you tried using `THREE.ObjectLoader` instead? Sorry about the current mess in the examples for this subject.

Comment: Personally I've had to revert to the r69 exporter and Blender 2.69. The current exporter is very inconsistent with skeletal animation exports.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - and from a key developer to boot!  Yes I have tried the objectloader but was really struggling with animations.  I got an obj importer to work just fine but getting a keyframed blender file into three.js was just a little bit tricky.  I'll keep watching this space.  I'm pretty sure Blender is still growing in popularity so I guess this may become key in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have a .js file begins with:

```js
  
"metadata": {
  "formatVersion" : 3.1,
  "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
  "vertices"      : 254,
  "faces"         : 364,
  "normals"       : 137,
  "colors"        : 0,
  "uvs"           : [],
  "materials"     : 1,
  "morphTargets"  : 0,
  "bones"         : 0
},
```

So i wanted to find the exporter like this post related to. So i had found Blender 2.73 + r69 exporter works. Only thing is it exports .json still. But it's the same format i wanted.

If anyone want to get this result. So clone this repo: "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js" and checkout r69. And copy "three.js\utils\exporters\blender\2.65\scripts\addons\io_mesh_threejs" to "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\scripts\addons". Start Blender -> File -> Preferences -> AddOns -> select it -> save it.